# HSEARCH700020: Unable to find the inverse side of the association on type 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' at path '.addresss<collection>'

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search, hibernate-search

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "Posting")
public class Posting implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "job_name")
@FullTextField()
private String jobName;

@Column(name = "position")
@FullTextField()
private String position;

@Column(name = "descriptions", length = 3000)
@FullTextField()
private String description;

@Column(name = "gender_requirement")
@FullTextField()
private String genderRequirement;

@Column(name = "job_requirement", length = 4000)
@FullTextField()
private String jobRequirement;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "posting_address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "posting_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
@IndexedEmbedded
private Collection<Address> addresss;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@NotNull
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

}
```

[image: Address.java]
[image: Province.java]

Hibernate ORM mapping:
type 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting':
path '.addresss.province.name':
failures:
- HSEARCH700020: Unable to find the inverse side of the association on type 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' at path '.addresss'. Hibernate Search needs this information in order to reindex 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' when 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Address' is modified. You can solve this error by defining the inverse side of this association,  either with annotations specific to your integration (@OneToMany(mappedBy = ...) in Hibernate ORM)  or with the Hibernate Search @AssociationInverseSide annotation. Alternatively, if you do not need to reindex 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' when 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Address' is modified, you can disable automatic reindexing with @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW).
path '.addresss.province':
failures:
- HSEARCH700020: Unable to find the inverse side of the association on type 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' at path '.addresss'. Hibernate Search needs this information in order to reindex 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' when 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Address' is modified. You can solve this error by defining the inverse side of this association,  either with annotations specific to your integration (@OneToMany(mappedBy = ...) in Hibernate ORM)  or with the Hibernate Search @AssociationInverseSide annotation. Alternatively, if you do not need to reindex 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' when 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Address' is modified, you can disable automatic reindexing with @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW).

Comment: See https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hsearch700020-unable-to-find-the-inverse-side-of-the-association-on-type/6551

Answer (score 0):

> I have an error

You also have an explanation, right there in the error message:

> Hibernate Search needs this information in order to reindex 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' when 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Address' is modified.

And even *two* solutions:

> You can solve this error by defining the inverse side of this association,  either with annotations specific to your integration (@OneToMany(mappedBy = ...) in Hibernate ORM)  or with the Hibernate Search @AssociationInverseSide annotation.

> Alternatively, if you do not need to reindex 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Posting' when 'com.codedecode.demo.entity.Address' is modified, you can disable automatic reindexing with @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)